# Taking OS snapshots & restoring them

Tags: linux, system-restore, disk-image

On Amazon AWS or other cloud platforms it is possible to take a full snapshot of a virtual machine and load a new VM from that image. Is it possible to somehow do the same for our desktops without virtualization?

The problem that I keep running into with my Linux installations is that my setup constantly gets messy or certain things suddenly stop working (maybe because of some update I did or some other software that I have installed). It would be awesome to completely restore everything to the previous "clean" snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a backup, and yes, it's entirely possible.

What virrualization brings is convenience and ease of back-end access. So it's easier to pull a complete image and restore it.

Backing up "bare metal" as it is called for physical machines, usually requires a little more effort as either the system must be able to be fully read by an internal process, or an external device needs to be able to copy the drive.

Look up bare metal backups for your preferred Linux flavor and see what options meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do backups pretty easily.

### Make a Backup

I like using `mksquashfs` because it lets use make one file with all of your filesystem. To use `mksquashfs` you can run the following command:

```sh
# mksquashfs / /your-backup-location.sfs -e /your-backup-location.sfs
```

This will generate one file with all of your files (preserving permissions, etc.). You can then copy this file to another drive.

If you are doing this locally, I suggest to `chroot` to your linux installation (from a live USB or similar) and then mounting that partition to a location such as `/mnt` and then running this command instead:

```sh
# mksquashfs /mnt /your-backup-location.sfs
```

### Restore Backup

To restore a backup run the following commands:

```sh
# unsquashfs /your-backup-location.sfs
# mv squashfs-root /mnt
```